# go command not found which is needed for installing CUE

Tags: linux, go

I am trying to install `go` in a docker image with the below commands:

```
- cd /usr/local
- wget -L "https://golang.org/dl/go1.20.1.linux-amd64.tar.gz"
- tar -xzvf go1.20.1.linux-amd64.tar.gz
- rm -f go1.20.1.linux-amd64.tar.gz
- echo "export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin" >> /etc/profile
- source /etc/profile
- /usr/local/go/bin version
- /usr/local/go/bin install cuelang.org/go/cmd/cue@latest
```

These commands are passed in a `.gitlab-ci.yml` in one of the stages and it throws an error at the end by saying `go not found` when I try to check the version.

What am I missing here? my ultimate goal is to install `CUE` but I want to install it via golang.

Comment: You can try to replace `go version` with `/usr/local/go version`, and same with `go install`

Comment: any reason not to use the standard go image?

Comment: @Fifi It gives `/usr/local/go: Is a directory` error

Comment: @DanielA.White Can you provide some names? I can try that

Comment: Your commands put `GOROOT` at `/usr/local/go/go`

Comment: sorry I didn't get your point @JimB

Comment: look at what you are downloading and extracting -- you are creating the path `/usr/local/go/go/`, so your binary is going to be in `/usr/local/go/go/bin` not `/usr/local/go/bin`. Fix how you create the directory structure.

Comment: I fixed it but doesn't work. I have updated the commands in the question. May be you can have a look and suggest me something @JimB

Comment: It gives me this error `/usr/local/go/bin: Is a directory` @JimB

Comment: yes it's a directory, why are you trying to execute it? You put the binary at `/usr/local/go/bin/go`

Comment: @whatsinthename You can’t execute a directory, you need to execute a command.

Comment: Ohh! yeah I missed that. My bad. Let me quickly fix that.

Comment: But I am already doing export path then why it is not able to recognize it globally?

Comment: It worked but I am not sure why exporting command to /etc/profile file doesn't work

Comment: Again what is "doesn't work"? exporting changes the variable in your current environment, and `/etc/profile` is sourced by new login shells.

Comment: Also since my goal is to install `cue` by trying it via `go` command, when I try to run `cue .....` it says cue command not found. Although go downloaded cue. How can I verify this installation. Any hint would help. I followed the official documentation

Comment: I literally had to use `golang` docker image and it resolved my problem.

Comment: You didn't add the GOBIN directory to your PATH either, so the installed `cue` binary was not in your PATH. The go docker image has these paths set for you by default, which is why it worked.

Comment: So can you help me to understand how exactly I can set these variables? Because I no where found on the documentation as well as echoing to the /etc/profile is not working. Should I try ~/.bashrc?

Comment: I can't fit how to manage environment variables in general into a single comment. If you want to see how they are set in a dockerfile, look at the dockerfile you used which worked, for example: https://github.com/docker-library/golang/blob/8b4411e7f38f2505c4fd3fd0aa579481c2aa85b2/1.20/bullseye/Dockerfile

Comment: cool. will check that